# i am trying to make a password system in python. i dont know whats wrong with this

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
import os

pasword = os.environ['PASSWORD']

askpassword = input("Enter Password : ")
if askpassword == (pasword)
    print ("Correct Password, you now have access to this code")
if not askpassword == (pasword)
exit()
```

this is my code, its telling me this error:

```
  File "main.py", line 6
    if askpassword == 'pasword'
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i am using https://replit.com by the way

Comment: Since @Matthew B answered the question I would like to add something. Never save password as unhashed data. Always use any sort of hashing. Like md5, sha***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix - you forgot a colon.

```
if askpassword == (pasword):
```

In python all control structures need to have a colon after them.

Comment: ok thank you im new to python